# Select a field from a table for two different values from two different tables

Tags: oracle

I have four tables as shown below.HL_STUDENT,HL_SEM1_CRS and HL_SEM2_CRS tables that has STUDENT as the primary key where as HL_TITLE doesn't have a STUDENT field and has the course number (CRS_NBR) as the key.

```
HL_STUDENT  A
HL_SEM1_CRS B
HL_SEM2_CRS C
HL_CRS_TITLE D
```

I need to get the STUDENT,CRS-1,CRS1-TITLE-DESC,CRS-2,CRS2-TITLE-DESC as shown below.I need course descripion for both Course 1 and Course 2.

```
STUDENT CRS-1  CRS1-TITLE-DESC  CRS-2  CRS2-TITLE-DESC
1        25    MATH             35     HISTORY
2        35    HISTORY          25     MATH
```

I was thinking of getting the solution by joining the HL_CRS_TITLE Table twice with different ALIAS as shown below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.STUDENT
               ,B.CRS_1
               ,D.CRS_TITLE_DESC
               ,C.CRS_2
               ,E.CRS_TITLE_DESC
FROM HL_STUDENT A 
LEFT JOIN HL_SEM1_CRS B ON A.STUDENT = B.STUDENT
LEFT JOIN HL_CRS_TITLE D ON D.CRS_NBR = B.CRS_1
LEFT JOIN HL_SEM2_CRS B ON A.STUDENT = B.STUDENT
LEFT JOIN HL_CRS_TITLE E ON E.CRS_NBR = B.CRS_2
```

Can you please suggest a better way to get the solution?

I'm querying against ORACLE DB.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem is in duplicates if you join students and courses in first semester and join it in second semester you see cross joined courses?

If its true you may use `FULL JOIN` between courses and join it with students and titles

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.STUDENT
           ,B.CRS_1
           ,D.CRS_TITLE_DESC
           ,B.CRS_2
           ,E.CRS_TITLE_DESC
FROM HL_STUDENT A 
JOIN (SELECT NVL(B1.STUDENT, B2.STUDENT) as STUDENT, B1.CRS_1, B2.CRS_2
       FROM HL_SEM1_CRS B1  
       FULL JOIN HL_SEM2_CRS B2 ON B1.STUDENT = B2.STUDENT AND B1.CRS_1 = B2.CRS_2) B ON A.STUDENT = B.STUDENT 
LEFT JOIN HL_CRS_TITLE D ON D.CRS_NBR = B.CRS_1
LEFT JOIN HL_CRS_TITLE E ON E.CRS_NBR = B.CRS_2
```

example without double join to HL_CRS_TITLE.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.STUDENT
           ,B.CRS_1
           ,nvl2(B.CRS_1, D.CRS_TITLE_DESC, null) as CRS_TITLE_DESC_1
           ,B.CRS_2
           ,nvl2(B.CRS_2, D.CRS_TITLE_DESC, null) as CRS_TITLE_DESC_2
FROM HL_STUDENT A 
JOIN (SELECT NVL(B1.STUDENT, B2.STUDENT) as STUDENT,nvl(B1.CRS_1, B2.CRS_2) as CRS,B1.CRS_1, B2.CRS_2
       FROM HL_SEM1_CRS B1  
       FULL JOIN HL_SEM2_CRS B2 ON B1.STUDENT = B2.STUDENT AND B1.CRS_1 = B2.CRS_2) B ON A.STUDENT = B.STUDENT 
LEFT JOIN HL_CRS_TITLE D ON D.CRS_NBR = B.CRS
```

Comment: hello,The problem is not with the duplicates.I need to get the course title for the records of both the semesters without the need of joining HL_CRS_TITLE two times.

Comment: I add example without joining HL_CRS_TITLE two times. But I don't see benefits of that solution

Comment: Thank you Michael for your time.For the time being,I think I will go with my original approach for joining the HL_CRS_TITLE  table twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a way to get course title for the records of both the semesters without the need of joining HL_CRS_TITLE two times.
I ran into a similar situation once and created a function to serve the purpose.

```
--Function DDL
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_GET_CRS_TITLE (IN_CRS_NBR IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2 
RESULT_CACHE
AS
LV_CRS_TITLE_DESC VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
SELECT CRS_TITLE_DESC
INTO   LV_CRS_TITLE_DESC
FROM   HL_CRS_TITLE
WHERE  CRS_NBR = IN_CRS_NBR;
RETURN LV_CRS_TITLE_DESC;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  RETURN 'NO_COURSE_EXISTS';
END;
/
```

You can re-write your query like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.STUDENT
               ,B.CRS_1
               ,F_GET_CRS_TITLE(B.CRS_1)
               ,C.CRS_2
               ,F_GET_CRS_TITLE(C.CRS_2)
FROM HL_STUDENT A 
LEFT JOIN HL_SEM1_CRS B ON A.STUDENT = B.STUDENT
LEFT JOIN HL_SEM2_CRS C ON A.STUDENT = C.STUDENT;
```

Comment: ,yes,I m looking for getting the course title for the records of both the semesters without the need of joining HL_CRS_TITLE two times.

Comment: ,Yes -I m looking for getting the course title for the records of both the semesters without the need of joining HL_CRS_TITLE two times.But is there a way that I can do this without using a function.I think the solution that you gave was for PL/SQL but I'm using PRO*COBOL.